# Batch script for ffmpeg to extract images from several video files

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

On Windows cmd trying this code to convert all .mp4 files in directory to set of images named "filename_imagenumber.jpeg"

```
 pushd %1

if not exist Images\ (
    mkdir Images
)

for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i %%F -r 1 -f image2 -qscale:v 2 "Images\%%~nF_image-%3d.jpeg"
)

popd
```

However ffmpeg's argument %3d is not interpreted by Windows cmd.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "is not interpreted"? What happens when you run it?

Comment: `%3` refers to the third argument passed to your batch script. If you want to use `%3d` literally, you should double the percent sign as follows: `"Images\%%~nF_image-%%3d.jpeg"`